# How to apply predict to xgboost cross validation

Tags: python, scikit-learn, xgboost

After some time searching google I feel this might be a nonsensical question, but here it goes. If I use the following code I can produce an xgb regression model, which I can then use to fit on the training set and evaluate the model

```
xgb_reg = xgb.XGBRegressor(objective='binary:logistic',
                           gamme = .12, 
                           eval_metric = 'logloss',
                           #eval_metric = 'auc', 
                           eta = .068,
                           subsample = .78,
                           colsample_bytree = .76,
                           min_child_weight = 9,
                           max_delta_step = 5,
                           nthread = 4)

start = time.time()
xgb_reg.fit(X_train, y_train)
print(start-time.time())

y_pred = xgb_reg.predict(X_test)
print(log_loss(y_test, y_pred))
```

Now, I want to take that a step further and use kfold cv to improve the model, so I have this

```
data_dmatrix = xgb.DMatrix(data=X_train,label=y_train)
params = {'objective':'binary:logistic','eval_metric':'logloss','eta':.068,
          'subsample':.78,'colsample_bytree':.76,'min_child_weight':9,
          'max_delta_step':5,'nthread':4}
xgb_cv = cv(dtrain=data_dmatrix, params=params, nfold=5, num_boost_round=20, metrics = 'logloss',seed=42)
```

However, this spits out a data frame and I can't use the .predict() on the test set.

I'm thinking I might not be understanding the fundamental concept of this but I'm hoping I'm just overlooking something simple.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

kfold cv doesn't make the model more accurate per se. In your example with xgb, there are many hyper parameters eg(subsample, eta) to be specified, and to get a sense of how the parameters chosen perform on unseen data, we use kfold cv to partition the data into many training and test samples and measure out-of-sample accuracy.

We usually try this for several possible values of a parameter and what gives the lowest average error. After this you would refit your model with the parameters. This [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34469038/understanding-python-xgboost-cv) and its answers discusses it.

For example, below we run something like what you did and we get only the train / test error for 1 set of values :

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import xgboost as xgb
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.datasets import make_classification

X, y = make_classification(n_samples=500,class_sep=0.7)
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y,
test_size=0.33, random_state=42)

data_dmatrix = xgb.DMatrix(data=X_train,label=y_train)
params = {'objective':'binary:logistic','eval_metric':'logloss',
          'eta':0.01,
          'subsample':0.1}
xgb_cv = xgb.cv(dtrain=data_dmatrix, params=params, nfold=5, metrics = 'logloss',seed=42) 

                 train-logloss-mean  train-logloss-std  test-logloss-mean  test-logloss-std
0            0.689600           0.000517           0.689820          0.001009
1            0.686462           0.001612           0.687151          0.002089
2            0.683626           0.001438           0.684667          0.003009
3            0.680450           0.001100           0.681929          0.003604
4            0.678269           0.001399           0.680310          0.002781
5            0.675170           0.001867           0.677254          0.003086
6            0.672349           0.002483           0.674432          0.004349
7            0.668964           0.002484           0.671493          0.004579
8            0.666361           0.002831           0.668978          0.004200
9            0.663682           0.003881           0.666744          0.003598
```

The last row is the result from last round, which is what we use for evaluation.

If we test over multiple values of `eta` ( and `subsample` for example:

```
grid = pd.DataFrame({'eta':[0.01,0.05,0.1]*2,
'subsample':np.repeat([0.1,0.3],3)})

    eta  subsample
0  0.01        0.1
1  0.05        0.1
2  0.10        0.1
3  0.01        0.3
4  0.05        0.3
5  0.10        0.3
```

Normally we can use [GridSearchCV](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.GridSearchCV.html) for this, but below is something that uses xgb.cv:

```
def fit(x):
    params = {'objective':'binary:logistic',
              'eval_metric':'logloss',
              'eta':x[0],
              'subsample':x[1]}
    xgb_cv = xgb.cv(dtrain=data_dmatrix, params=params, 
    nfold=5, metrics = 'logloss',seed=42)
    return xgb_cv[-1:].values[0]

grid[['train-logloss-mean','train-logloss-std',
'test-logloss-mean','test-logloss-std']] = grid.apply(fit,axis=1,result_type='expand')

    eta  subsample  train-logloss-mean  train-logloss-std  test-logloss-mean  test-logloss-std
0  0.01        0.1            0.663682           0.003881           0.666744          0.003598
1  0.05        0.1            0.570629           0.012555           0.580309          0.023561
2  0.10        0.1            0.503440           0.017761           0.526891          0.031659
3  0.01        0.3            0.646587           0.002063           0.653741          0.004201
4  0.05        0.3            0.512229           0.008013           0.545113          0.018700
5  0.10        0.3            0.414103           0.012427           0.472379          0.032606
```

We can see for `eta = 0.10` and `subsample = 0.3` gives the best result, so next you just need to refit the model with these parameters:

```
xgb_reg = xgb.XGBRegressor(objective='binary:logistic',
                           eval_metric = 'logloss',
                           eta = 0.1,
                           subsample = 0.3)

xgb_reg.fit(X_train, y_train)
```

Comment: well, that would explain why I couldn't find any articles on it. Thanks for the detailed response.

Comment: glad it was useful :)

Comment: @StupidWolf: Why is objective function: binary:logistic is used when it is regression problem?

Answer (score -1):

You can get this info from: https://xgboost.readthedocs.io/en/stable/parameter.html

[default=reg:squarederror]

The objective function for regressor should be what is here and not 'binary:logistic' as was originally posted and carried forward.  My statement was just to point that out as @innovator-programmer pointed out

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).